# How can I open Google Chrome in Presentation mode using a shell script

Tags: google-chrome, startup, script, command-line, fullscreen

Previously in 10.6.8, I was able to start Google using 
open /Applications/Chrome.app --args --kiosk http://www.google.com

Now, on newer systems, that does not work anymore correctly. The only way to get rid of the address bar seams to be using of the presentation mode.
Does anyone know the switch to call that mode?

I use the shell script for a presentation computer to start the browser on startup automatically in fullscreen mode.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check this on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/209980/mac-osx-start-google-chrome-in-kiosk-mode-error ... Seems like kiosk is broken in Lion+ and the work around is AppleScript.

Answer (score 3):

I tested this out and then it wouldn't let me exit kiosk mode. I had to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to get out of Google Chrome. Save the following to a script, something like `ChromeKiosk.sh` and `chmod +x ChromeKiosk.sh` to get it to run.

```
#!/bin/bash
open "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args --kiosk http://www.google.com.au
```

This will open Google Chrome to the `http://www.google.com.au` webpage. Change it as you need. Copy and paste the rest of the script

If you want to turn it into an AppleScript so that you can create an application that can in turn be automatically run each time the computer reboots to a default specified user, use the following code and when you save the script, change it's type to Application

```
do shell script "/bin/bash open \"/Applications/Google Chrome.app\" --args --kiosk"
```

It's requires the `\` *(escape sequence)* before the `"` because of the way the shell reads the spacing between the words **Google** and **Chrome** in the filename. You can also write it as

```
do shell script "/bin/bash open /Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app --args --kiosk"
```

It's just that I've never favoured the look of seeing a escape before a backslash. It's too messy. Stick with either the BashScript option at the top or use the 1st of 2 AppleScript lines and save it as an Application type.

Comment: I made a nice little native application that will do this for you now too - http://danijeljames.github.io/Chrome-Kiosk-Mode - download the DMG file.